# Passing variable number of args from Python to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I want to build a query with variable number of arguments:

```
group_ids = ', '.join(str(Rules[s].value) for s in groups)
cursor.execute("SELECT a, b, c
    FROM my_table
    WHERE a IN (%(group_ids)s)
    ;",
    {'group_ids': group_ids})
```

But that results in a warning (which is not shown by default!):
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '30, 12'
and only the first value is used, the rest omitted.
So I'm using this little hack right now:

```
group_ids = ', '.join(str(Rules[s].value) for s in groups)
cursor.execute('\n'.join("SELECT a, b, c",
    "FROM my_table",
    "WHERE a IN %s" % group_ids
    ;")
```

I know these are valid values (coming from an enum) but I would get rid of even the remotest possibility of SQL injections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Construct the parameter part of the SQL dynamically:

```
group_ids = [str(Rules[s].value) for s in groups]
sql = "SELECT a, b, c FROM my_table WHERE a IN (%s)" % (
    ','.join(['%s'] * len(group_ids))
)
cursor.execute(sql, group_ids)
```

NOTE: Above will not work for an empty id list. Guard it with a condition:

```
if not group_ids:
    # skip execution of the query.
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Py
thon 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: @MKesper, Make sure you're passing `sql`, and `group_ids`, a list of strings.

Comment: How would you include another variable?
For example:

`"....WHERE a IN (%s) AND c=%s..."`

This doesn't seem to work:
`cursor.execute(sql, group_ids, c_value)`

Comment: @DavidManess, You should pass parameter as a list: `cursor.execute(sql, group_ids + [c_value])`